# How to remove automatic generated <p> tag in Home page

Tags: plugins, code, homepage

I am new to Wordpress and need some helps here. I am trying to add posts that have written codes for the demonstrated purpose of programming languages.

I installed SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin. The post looks great when I preview it or view the post under category. However, it seems that Wordpress generated `<p>` tag in my Home page and messed up the codes of the post. I am not sure how to fix this.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add an example for the wrong output.

Comment: Please see http://popslinger.org/wordpress/ If you click the post you will see the entire written codes, but it doesn't show in Home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On archive pages like a blog home page the [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) is used normally. As the name says it shows just a snippet from your post.

Most content filters are not applied to the excerpt, they work on [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) only.

Fix: change your template, replace `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()` in archive pages.

Comment: If I chagne my template to the_content(). The homepage won't use excerpt anymore. Is there a way to keep excerpt and still show part of my written codes as excerpt? +1

Comment: No. The excerpt just takes a number of first words. It strips all markup. Otherwise there would be open tags, shortcodes without context … you could write a [custom excerpt](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+excerpt) function that runs over the `post_content` and keeps the markup intact. But there are always some pitfalls. I wouldn't recommend it.